# How can I tell the worklight hybrid client to used a specific certificate that was downloaded to the device?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, client-certificates, x509

I copied the client certificate to the device, save to local storage, then install certificate from storage. I'm using DataPower to terminate the SSL and validate the certificate before forwarding requests to Worklight.

When I try to connect, it fails with log message stating "establisheSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists: false" and an SSLHandshakeException.

I assume this means the client is not sending the client certificate.  This all happens under the covers with Worklight, so I'm trying to figure out how to tell it to use a specific certificate.

```
02-11 12:29:23.147: D/NONE(5995): wlclient init success
02-11 12:29:23.147: D/NONE(5995): establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
02-11 12:29:23.157: D/NONE(5995): Request [/apps/services/api/MyMobileApp/android/init]
02-11 12:29:23.237: D/HttpPostRequestSender(5995): WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:47 :: Sending request https://10.75.29.27/MQTTClient/apps/services/api/MyMobileApp/android/init
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995): WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onException in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:154 :: onException
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x784e3468: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995): error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x7849ae90:0x00000003)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:468)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:232)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:481)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:382)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at com.worklight.wlclient.WLHybridRequestSender.run(WLHybridRequestSender.java:63)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x784e3468: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995): error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x7849ae90:0x00000003)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:425)
02-11 12:29:23.477: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(5995):  ... 13 more
02-11 12:29:23.497: E/NONE(5995): [/apps/services/api/MyMobileApp/android/init] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.
02-11 12:29:23.507: I/NONE(5995): Failed connecting to Worklight Server.
02-11 12:29:28.102: E/ViewRootImpl(5995): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

The problem is we need to be able to specify what Client Certificate to use on the WL.CLient instead of WL.Server pushing the the Client Certificate to the WL.Client.  I saw an Android demo of using credentials obtained from an NFC card using a custom created Cordova plugin and ChallengeHandlers.  While a plugin could be created to get the credentials, I don't think it solves the problem when you add DataPower into the mix.

Answer (score 2):

Worklight will only use a certificate that it has provisioned unto the device, not one that you place there manually.

Worklight's User Cert Auth feature can use your PKI of choice, to provision the client device with a x509 client certificate.  However, it first takes care to validate device, app and user has authenticated before the certificate is installed for future use.

To learn more about Worklight's User Certificate Authentication feature visit:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_user_CA.html

Another option is to have Datapower do one way SSL.  Meaning it can accept but not require a client certificate.

Comment: Added additional detail to original post. You can use a Cordova plugin to get credentials, but with DataPower in the mix there doesn't seem to be a way to use DataPower to do the certificate validation.

Comment: David, I'm not familiar with that plugin.  Do you have a link with more info?